# Issue when importing win32api

Tags: python, python-3.x

[Error code in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaHEx.jpg)

```
import datetime
import os
import smtplib
import webbrowser

import pyttsx3  # pip install pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr  # pip install speechRecognition
import wikipedia  # pip install wikipedia

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
print(voices[1].id)
```

Error code text:

```
import win32com.client
File "C:\Users\OM\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\win32com\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
import win32api, sys, os
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: pyttsx3 in c:\users\om\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (2.71)
Requirement already satisfied: pypiwin32; "win32" in sys_platform in c:\users\om\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from pyttsx3) (223)
Requirement already satisfied: pywin32>=223 in c:\users\om\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from pypiwin32; "win32" in sys_platform->pyttsx3) (225)

Comment: You need to add the directory where this files are located. It seems it's looking in a different path.

Comment: Both directory are same.

Comment: It seems it's looking for init_.py file within and could not find it. You need to check if actually this file exist. If not you might have to add it.

Comment: __init__.py is available.